# Google earth crashing in c# application

Tags: c#, google-earth

I'm using google earth in my C# application and it almost works fine, but occasionally I get the message

> Google earth has encountered a problem ...

and supposedly it *crashes* (Although it's still running underneath).
what seems to be the problem here?
I thought maybe the problem is calling the google earth methods too frequently so I fixed it but still no good news...

One of the functions it crashes in is :

```
puvlic void clearKMLFile()
{
 try
  {
   XmlDocument mainXml = new XmlDocument();
   mainXml.Load(strKMLPath);
   string strRoot = "kml/Document/Folder";
   XmlNode ndPlaceRoot = mainXml.SelectSingleNode(strRoot);

   for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
   {
    for(int i=0;i<ndPlaceRoot.ChildNodes.Count;i++)
    {
     if(ndPlaceRoot.ChildNodes[i].Name == "Placemark")
     {
      if(ndPlaceRoot.ChildNodes[i].Attributes.Count != 0)
      {
       ndPlaceRoot.RemoceChild(ndPlaceRoot.ChildNodes[i]);
       mainXml.Save(strKMLPath);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
  try 
  {
   ge.OpenKmlFile(strKMLPath,1);   //this is the only Google earth API method used here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   MessageBox.Show("An error occurred in clearring process!");
  }
}
```

The error message itself :
[image]

Comment: I do not understand why this post got these negative points, I've obviously did my searching before asking here and the question is quite clear ..

Comment: How are you using Google Earth in your application? Show your code. What do you mean by "crashes", if it's still running? Your question isn't as clear as you think.

Comment: This is a general problem, not specific in a part of of my code, any way I added one of the methods that does the most trouble. 
By Crashing I mean that when the message apears I see the google earth map flying to my location but I can't use the window and when I close the message google earth exits.

Comment: What class is the object `ge`?

Comment: @SynerCoder : ApplicationGE from google earth API (interop.eathlib.dll)

Comment: You catch the exception but don't do anything with it. Can you tell us  the exception type, stacktrace en message?

Comment: @SynerCoder : Actually my message box doesn't appear proving that it doesn't throw an exception. I've added the picture of the error that comes up. The google earth itself pops this up! After seeing this I can still work with my application but after a few second another message is shown saying that google has had an error and when I click 'ok' google earth exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what the problem was ...
For future refrence:
I was calling the `ge.OpenKmlFile()` method two times in a row very fast in my code, so google earth was crashing. Fixed the calls and the problem went away for now.